# XML::Twig.pm vs XML::Twig.pm.slow is this an internal CPAN difference?

Tags: perl, cpan, xml-twig

Searching XML + Twig under the all option produces two results for Xml::Twig.
In the listings they are shown as XML::Twig but the link itself differs by the suffix .slow on one of these.

Is there a difference in the modules, or is this some kind of CPAN Area51 thing?

Comment: They both link to the same source. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the _slow one is the source one. It is processed during installation to generate the .pm one, which is the one Perl loads. The processing inlines some methods, for speed, and filters out some lines for really old versions of perl (5.6 and older).